# Is there a class component library to Vue that does not use decorators?

Tags: vue.js

The Vue [class component library](https://class-component.vuejs.org/)  uses the `@Component` decorator, and must thus be transpiled to work. Is there a way to use Vue class components without this decorator? Like, either a work-around or another similar library?

Use-case: Lower commitment for a legacy project, but still possible to analyze with tsc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpiled environment is the expected scenario of use for Vue. It relies on custom .vue format and may lack some features without it, as well as the support of some third-party libraries because they rely on it.

The use of classes never was a good idea in Vue because it doesn't follow OOP paradigm. A class isn't instantiated directly but used as syntactic structure that is translated to `Vue.component` definition. Vue class components have inherent problems, one of which is poor support for TypeScript types. If Vue classes aren't already used in the project, there are reasons for them to not be the first choice.

In case there's a necessity to use Vue class components, this can be done in vanilla ES6 because decorators proposal is syntactic sugar, decorators are functions with specific signatures that are applied to classes and members and *decorate* them.

```
@foo
@bar()
class Baz {}
```

is the same as

```
let Baz = foo(bar()(class Baz {}))
```

[Different decorator types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) are applied in different ways, also there are some differences between TypeScript and Babel legacy decorators.

```
@Component
class Foo extends Vue {
  @Provide('bar') baz = 'bar'
}
```

is translated to

```
let Foo = class Foo extends Vue {
  constructor() {
    this.baz = 'bar'
  }
}

Provide('bar')(Foo.prototype, 'baz')

Foo = Component(Foo);
```

Comment: Oh, so I can just manually apply the decorator? Assuming it's the only one used, or it will get messy. Btw, my reason to use classes is to _increase_ type-safety with TypeScript, so props etc can be properly typed. You say that's wrong?

Comment: Yes, decorator syntax is a sugar, as I said. They aren't pretty without it, especially member decorators. TS favors classes in terms of type safety but decorators are unsafe, and Vue classes have several points that cannot guarantee type safety by design, including props types. This was one of reasons to switch from class to functional components in React, and Vue learned this lesson too. So no, Vue classes aren't a good way to provide type safety, [composition API](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

With  Vue 3 typescript is well supported, you could create your component as follows :

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  //the component options like data,props,computed...
})
```

For more details check [the official docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typescript-support)

A running [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-y7bdv) to get started

Comment: Hm, props etc kind of remove the possibility to type-check the class, which was the purpose. I just wanted to avoid compilation while doing this.

Comment: The question is about class components. Vue 3 ditched official support for them because they have innate problems.

Comment: @EstusFlask but there's only `vue-class-component` which is officially supported by vue 2, th version of vue-class-component compatible with vue 3 uses `@options` instead of `@component`